# Printing objects with bool true from an arraylist JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist, boolean

The getArrayStringListFalse method should be printing out the objects with the bool false

And the getArrayStringListTrue method should do the same with the objects with bool true

```
import java.util.*;


public class Issue {

private static ArrayList<newIssue> list = new ArrayList<>();


public static ArrayList<newIssue> getArrayStringListFalse(){

    for(int i = 0; i < list.size();i++){
        if (!list.get(i).returned){
            System.out.println("["+"["+i+"] "+list.get(i)+"]");
        }else {
            System.out.println("You have no unsolved issues!");
        };
    };
    return null;
}

public static ArrayList<newIssue> getArrayStringListTrue(){

    for(int i = 0; i < list.size();i++){
        if (list.get(i).returned){
            System.out.println("["+"["+i+"] "+list.get(i)+"]");
        }else {
            System.out.println("You have no solved issues!");
        };
    };
    return null;
}



public static void removeIssue(){
    for (int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++){;
        System.out.println("["+"["+i+"] "+list.get(i)+"]");
    }
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Which one would you like to mark as solved?");
    int choice = scan.nextInt();
    newIssue issue = list.get(choice);
    issue.returned = true;
}

public static void addIssue(){
    System.out.println("---Create a new issue---");
    System.out.println("Describe the issue: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String text= scan.nextLine();
    newIssue issue = new newIssue(text);
    list.add(issue);
}
}
```

It is working sort of except im printing out the "issue + the bool value" so it looks something like this. [I have no catsfalse].

Also the for loop should only print out the true/false depending on the method the amount of existing true/false objects now if I have 2 true objects and 1 false and use the false method it prints out one false then the else statement.

Hope you understand what Im trying to do

```
public class newIssue {

public String issueText;
public boolean returned = false;

public newIssue(String issueText){
    this.issueText = issueText;
}

public String toString(){
    return issueText + returned;
}



}
```

Comment: remove the `else` case

Comment: if you want to print out a message for the case _"You have no solved issues!"_ then you cannot do that inside the loop and instead have to do it **after** the loop when you found no matching data in the loop itself.

Comment: A) read about java naming conventions - class names go UpperCase - always. B) rethink your naming in the first place: a method name should tell what the method is doing. You have to **explain** what the method is doing (and even with that explanations, the whole thing doesn't make much sense).

Comment: Then: what is the point of a method to **return** null - always? You see: either a method should **have** a result, then you return a real value; or there is no result, then the method should be **void**. In your case: why not **return** a sublist of those elements that match a certain criteria? And then, instead of printing stuff right there, you first **collect** those sublists, to then pass the list to a generic "print method", that just knows how to print stuff? Hint: a method should have **one** responsibility. Not two, not three. One!

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify it a lot, if you can use `java-8` and `steams`:

```
// print all elements with returned == true    
list.stream().filter(i -> i.returned).forEach(System.out::println);
```

and

```
// print all elements with returned == false    
list.stream().filter(i -> !i.returned).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify like this:

```
public static ArrayList<newIssue> getArrayStringListFalse(){
boolean flag=false;
for(int i = 0; i < list.size();i++){
    if (!list.get(i).returned){
        System.out.println("["+"["+i+"] "+list.get(i)+"]");
        flag = true;
    }
}
if(!flag){
    System.out.println("You have no unsolved issues!");
}
return null;
}

public static ArrayList<newIssue> getArrayStringListTrue(){
boolean flag=false;
for(int i = 0; i < list.size();i++){
    if (list.get(i).returned){
        System.out.println("["+"["+i+"] "+list.get(i)+"]");
        flag = true;
    }
}
if(!flag){
        System.out.println("You have no solved issues!");
};
return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why it prints the object + the bool as a string after?

Comment: its because you have the to string method returning issueText + returned. You can change it to anything you want to be printed. if you want a space or a colon to seperate your issue string and boolean, try: return issueText + " : " + returned;

Comment: @Kirdid Because thats how you programmed your `toString()` method! This method is called by default when you print an Object using System.out.println. If you want to print something else either change the `toString()` method or programm manualle what you want to print by using other methods.